# How can I set default value in insert into select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a table and I want to copy this table to another table but I want to new column to copied table. This new column should have same value as 1.

This is sample source table.

| pk_id | customer_id | vehicle_id | relation_type | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null |
| 3 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null |
| 4 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null |

This is expected result.

| case status | pk_id | customer_id | vehicle_id | relation_type | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 3 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 4 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null |

This is my source table scrpit.

```
  create table #Result
 (
    pk_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    fk_customer_id INT,
    fk_vehicle_id INT,
    relation_type SMALLINT,
    end_date DATETIME,
 )
```

This is my destination create table script. I tried DEFAULT 1 but does not work.

```
  create table #Resultt
 (
    case_status INT DEFAULT 1,
    pk_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    fk_customer_id INT,
    fk_vehicle_id INT,
    relation_type SMALLINT,
    end_date DATETIME,
 )
```

And this is insert into select query.

```
  insert into #Resultt select * from #Result
```

Comment: FWIW, it *would have* worked, had you listed out the columns explicitly

Comment: If these were physical tables you could make the Result table system versioned.  Then an update to case_status would create a numbered snapshot all of the rows and you could accumulate history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* list the columns, but you can do:

```
insert into #Resultt
    select 1, r.*
    from #Result r;
```

However, I recommend being explicit:

```
insert into #Resultt (case_status, pk_id, customer_id, vehicle_id, relation_type, end_date)
    select 1, r.pk_id, r.customer_id, r.vehicle_id, r.relation_type, r.end_date
    from #Result r;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it I believe

```
 SELECT 1 as 'case_status', OLDTABLE.* INTO NEWTABLE FROM OLDTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the same exact values you can change your #Resultt table to this:

```
   create table #Resultt
 (
    case_status INT DEFAULT 1,
    pk_id INT,
    fk_customer_id INT,
    fk_vehicle_id INT,
    relation_type SMALLINT,
    end_date DATETIME,
 )
```

and you  can insert into that table like this:

```
 insert into #Resultt
    select 1, r.*
    from #Result r;
```

The identity in your second table wouldn't let you insert the exact same value from the `pk_id`